# Invalid data while decoding a byte[] using gzip

Tags: c#, compression, gzip

I have a message payload and one of the properties is "contents" which contains a gzip compressed data. Ive extracted out the property contents from the message and published it to another queue. This next queue then needs to decompress the byte[] and then extract out the original string.

I get an "Invalid data while decoding" exception when decompressing the byte[] received from the previous queue. Ive actually taken the gzip compressed data and run it through online gzip decompressor to check that it is valid and it is. Im not sure why it is unable to decompress the byte[] even though an online gzip decompressor can do it without issue.

Code for how I am compressing and sending the original message (I am using a dynamic object cause i am extracting other properties which are not show in this snippet):

```
dynamic messageObject = new ExpandoObject();   
messageObject.PreviousWorkerResult = message.PreviousWorkersResults;
messageObject.Contents = GzipHelper.Compress(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedMessage));

var serializedExpandoObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObject, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
     NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
     ContractResolver = new CustomCamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
});

body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedExpandoObject);
                
 _bus.Advanced.Publish(exchange,
                       queueName,
                       mandatory: true,
                       messageProperties: properties,
                       body: body);
```

Code for extracting the gzipped compressed data property "contents":

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message.Payload);
string contents = data.contents;
 
var properties = new MessageProperties()
{
    ContentType = "gzip"
};
await messageQueuePublisher.PublishAsync(contents, dto.SendTo, properties);
```

Code for the receiving end to decompress. This is where the exception is being thrown on the GzipHelper.Decompress(body):

```
if (properties.ContentType == "gzip")
{
    var decompressed = GzipHelper.Decompress(body);
    jsonMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);
}
```

Code for the Compress and Decompress in GzipHelper:

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gzip = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        {
            gzip.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        return memory.ToArray();
    }
}

public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
            return resultStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         throw new Exception(e.ToString());
    }
}
```